# Powershell - merge .txt files into one - based on modified date

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with thousands of files

**File1:**

```
A B C

A B C
```

**File 2:**

```
1 2123

2345
```

**ResultFile (output):**

```
A B C

A B C



1 2123

2345
```

How can I merge those into one file - with some space between each file-content?
I also want just those files modified today

This is what I have now

```
Get-ChildItem H:\myFolder-include *.txt -rec | ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} |  out-file H:\test.txt
```

How can I add the date-condition in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to filter data passed along the pipeline:

```
$startOfToday = (Get-Date).Date
Get-ChildItem H:\myFolder-include *.txt -Recurse | Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt $startOfToday | ForEach-Object {$_ |gc ; ""} | Out-File H:\test.txt
```

Comment: gc : Cannot find path 'H:\1.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:105
+ ... bject LastWriteTime -gt $startOfToday | ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} |  ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (H:\1.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
gc : Cannot find path 'H:\2.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:105

Answer (score 0):

If you only want files that have been modified today, you would put a `Where-Object` into your code before the `ForEach-Object` section

```
Get-ChildItem H:\myFolder-include *.txt -rec |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | 
ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} | out-file H:\test.txt
```

That would filter out files that have not been modified in the last day before they go into the foreach loop.